# Access objects from project in sandbox environment PHP

Tags: rally

Is there a way I can access my project under Sandbox? I'm able to use the lookup method, find in order to fetch all the features from a project under the Yahoo! subscription, but how would I be able to do this for projects under Sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. In the query to find specific features, I had to include the query parameter "workspace" to the sandbox reference which is (for 1.43) : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/workspace/7189290105.js". I included the reference of the project as well which directly fetched all the features for my project. In addition, if you seek to only fetch features from your specific project and not from the ones on top of it, you have to include the "pageScopeUp" field into the query. You have to set this field to false:

`$queryParams = array(
      'query' => "",
      'fetch' => 'true',
      'pagesize' => 100,
      'start' => 1, 
      'workspace' => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/workspace/7189290105.js",
      'project' => "whatever the project reference is",
      'projectScopeUp' => false
    );
    $results = Connection::rally()->findWithQueryParameters('feature',
       $queryParams);`

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP code have you used Rally sandbox server URL?

https://sandbox.rallydev.com/

Here is a WebServices URL specific to Sandbox:

https://sandbox.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/